# Can I limit support of my app to just iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I would like to know if it's ok to limit support for my iOS app to iOS 13 only? In that case, my app won't run on older devices such as iPhone 6 and 6+ which only support iOS 12.

I am aware of the limited user reach. As per Apple's latest stats, 70% of iPhone users have already updated to iOS 13. I am ok with that number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your numbers are correct,
https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

You can limit your app only for iOS 13+, Because that number increasing every day.that is the different between iOS and android. every time iOS latest version run on half of devices after going 6-9 months of its release .

Answer (score 0):

It is fine. Just set your app target to above 13.0. and everything will be fine. I made app with SwiftUI which can only run above iOS13 and it is working like charm.

Comment: Cool! I love SwiftUI! I built a prototype of my app using SwiftUI but in the end, I had to go back to UIKit since SwiftUI still couldn't achieve what I had on my design. Thanks for your input!